# How do I know the total length of the data read from a CSV file?

Tags: csv, go, foreach

How do I know the total length of the data read from a CSV file ?

```
func main(){

openfile, _ := os.Open(filepath)

        //read the data of file
        filedata, _ := csv.NewReader(openfile).ReadAll()

        for e, value := range filedata {

             // what should I write here for getting the total length of the data?

        }
}
```

Comment: The number of rows is `len(filedata)`. The number of columns in the current row is `len(value)`.  The total size in bytes of the file is `s, err := openfile.Stat(); n := s.Size()`

Comment: if i want to get the number of total rows of the file , how do i do it after i open the file and before the "foreach" function?

Comment: Use the expression `len(filedata)` to get the total number of rows in the file.  The expression can be evaluated any time after the variable `filedata` is set to the file rows.

Comment: did you mean declare a variable like lengthofRow:= len(filedata) before the "for e,value := range file data {}"?

Comment: Use `len(filedata)` everywhere that you need the the number of rows. The expression `len(filedata)` compiles to a local variable access. There's no need to declare yet another variable.  The use of len is covered [in the Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a "problems.csv" file with 3 rows.

```
5+5,10
7+3,10
1+1,2
```

To get the total number of rows of this csv file:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    openfile, err := os.Open("problems.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    filedata, err := csv.NewReader(openfile).ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    totalQuestions := len(filedata)
    fmt.Println("Total no: of rows:", totalQuestions)
    for e, value := range filedata {
        fmt.Println(e, value)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Total no: of rows: 3
0 [5+5 10]
1 [7+3 10]
2 [1+1 2]
```

Comment: ya, this answer is good, but i really encounter a problem which after i read the file , it just show 0 rows, i am mad but don know how to do, anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: There might be some problem with your csv file. Make sure you are printing errors after opening the file and reading from csv file. So that you can understand what's going wrong.

Comment: thank you very much, but i have one more thing to ask, if i want to put all the data into slices/array in the CSV file for further checking , how do i do ? many of the tutorial video did not teach this on youtube.

Comment: Did you mean putting all the data read from csv file into an array?  filedata, err := csv.NewReader(openfile).ReadAll(). Here "filedata" is  a 2 dimensional array of type [][]string

Comment: then how do i identifying each of the [][] ? maybe i want to take it out to do some verifying or compare and so on.. how do i put them into a array or slices and take them out ?maybe my english is really poor, but you can try to email me to giving the answer also, thank you. jinghao0958@gmail.com